# Non-nullable property must contain a non-null value warning on EF relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

C# compiler shows me `Non-nullable property must contain a non-null value` on:

- EF `relationships`
- `DbSet`

According to this documentation: [Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset) I could get rid of this warning for `DbSet` using:

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}
    
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers => Set<Customer>();
    public DbSet<Order> Orders => Set<Order>();
}
```

**What is the best way to get rid of this warning for EF `relationships` as well for the following example below** (without using `#pragma warning disable CS8618`) ?

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Customer(string username)
    {
        // still gets warning for `Orders`
        Username = username;
    }
}
```

And on the other side of relationship:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }

    public Log(string description, Guid customerId)
    {
        // still gets warning for `Job`
        Description = description;
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really use nullable reference types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question I believe this is the most suitable way of removing warning in EF `relationships`:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; } = null!;

    public Customer(string username)
    {
        Username = username;
    }
}
```

And on the other side of relationship:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; } = null!;

    public Log(string description, Guid customerId)
    {
        Description = description;
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }
}
```

But if someone has a better idea please feel free to share it.

Comment: yes, I think the best way is either to initialize them or else to change your data model, but then you wouldn't work anymore with nullable types